# Port forwarding (or rather "clone") a port to an another port for an application?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have an app running on port 32400 (Plex server), and the port number cannot be changed (but if possible that's welcomed, but still, in the question assume I have an app that's impossible to change). I want to access to the app from the internet, through HTTPS connection. There is an tool "ssl-proxy-linux" that does basically forward port 443 to an other port (e.g. 1443) with LetsEncrypt SSL enabled, but in order to apply this tool to an app, the app need to be running on port 443.

So, basically the flow should be like: app running on 32400 -> ** some software that does port forward? clone? the port 32400 to 443 ** -> the identical app running on 443 -> LetsEncrypt SSL app -> 1443 (now I'm accessing the app from a url like `https://myplexapp.com:1443`)

I tried socat `socat TCP-LISTEN:32400,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:443` but I get `E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:32400}, 16): Address already in use` error. Apparently this tool is for like port forwarding, but not for, let's say, port cloning, I guess?

So, is this kind of stuff possible, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to access to the app from the internet, through an HTTPS connection.

This is typically done with a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). The principle is that the reverse proxy gets HTTPS requests and is configured to pass those requests on to e.g. Plex on port 32400. So the flow is essentially:

```
Internet --> Router (443) --> Reverse Proxy (443 -> 32400) --> Plex
```

Regarding the program you mention in your original question, I am not familiar with that tool, so I can't really comment on how you might go about setting it up. But as an FYI, web servers (e.g. Apache and Nginx) support Let's Encrypt certificates and can have the ability to act as reverse proxies as well (and from personal experience, it's relatively simple to set up Plex behind one of these).

For URL access, your domain would point at your router and the router would port forward requests to the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried socat socat TCP-LISTEN:32400,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:443 but I get E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:32400}, 16): Address already in use error.

You told it to **listen on** port 32400 and connect to port 443. That's kind of backwards, according to your question – the app you have is *already* listening on port 32400, you want the relay tool to listen on 443 and **connect to** localhost:32400.

---

The 'dnat' feature in nftables (or REDIRECT in iptables) might be a better option, as it doesn't relay any data but rewrites the actual connection attempt instead. Adding a rule that matches on port 443 and DNATs to 127.0.0.1:32400 would achieve what you want.